# How to limit a process' memory usage while it is running?

Tags: process, memory

On my server, I have a long running batch process, `process_a`, which have been running for several days now. I don't mind the duration of which the process needs. The problem is how `process_a` always hogs ALL (99%) of the memory (RAM) to itself. I have `process_b` which I really need to be ran now. However, `process_b` is always hanging presumably because of insufficient RAM.

**Is there a way to limit a process' memory usage while it is running?**

I do not want to restart `process_a` because all the progress made could be lost. I am not the owner of the program that runs `process_a`, so I cannot modify `process_a` to save progress checkpoints at regular intervals. I am thinking of maybe somehow forcing half the memory of `process_a` to be dumped to swap in order to regain some memory for `process_b`.

All the answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process) and [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1424/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-amount-of-memory-a-particular-process-can-use-in-uni?noredirect=1&lq=1) does not address the fact the the process is running.

Comment: You can use `cgclassify` to move an existing process to a cgroup, so you can use this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125024/260978. Example for cgclassify: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40247/260978

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit memory usage for a single Linux process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process) and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19111/use-cgroup-to-limit-the-memory-usage-of-virtualbox

Comment: @Olorin The first answer you refer to specifies that the process is executed by `cgexec -g memory:myGroup pdftoppm` which means that I need to start the process with `cgexec` in the first place. The second answer also does not mention any thing about limiting the process memory usage while it is running. Do you have any reference to support that `cgclassify` can be used to reduce  a process' RAM usage _while the process is running_?

Comment: *That's literally what the other post (example for cgclassify) is about*.

Comment: So if `process_a` is running with full RAM, when I set a limit using `cgclassify`, what happens to the used memory that is over the limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `process_a` does not use the memory actively, then it will be swapped out when `process_b` starts.

So if you do not see that `process_a`'s memory is swapped out, then it could be because `process_a` is using the memory actively.

So how can you tell `process_a` to be inactive for a while?

You suspend it.

```
kill -TSTP $pid
```

Then you run `process_b` and let `process_a` move to swap.

If you want to push more memory out to swap check out: https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/tree/master/swapout

Finally when `process_b` is done, you release the brake on `process_a`:

```
kill -CONT $pid
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Check for the priority of the process

Higher priority is -20
lower prioritty is +19
Neutral is 0

if process_a is having highher priority based on your requirement reduce the priority (-20 to +19). Higher the priority it will consumes most of resources


You can try with ulimit command options too
```

Comment: How does this limit the process’ memory usage?